# How to make my monster face the right direction?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm having a problem making my monster facing the right direction.
Here is my code:

```
void RotateMonster(Monster monster)
{
     float deltaX = monster.Target.X - monster.coordinate.X;
     float deltaY = monster.Target.Y - monster.coordinate.Y;
     float tangentable = deltaX / deltaY;
     monster.Rotation = (float)Math.Atan(tangentable);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the monster walks backwards it faces the wrong direction in short can someone please explain for me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Watch out that if the monster move parallel to the X axis the deltaY will be 0 causing a divide by zero exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the sign of the `deltaX` and `deltaY` values to determine what to do with the result of the `Atan` method.

The `Atan` method doesn't know if you used positive or negative values to calculate the tangent, e.g. it can't tell the difference between `100/50` and `-100/-50`. For some combinations you have to add half a rotation to the angle.

I don't have a grip on exactly what values, but basically something like this:

```
float angle = (float)Math.Atan(tangentable);
if ((deltaX < 0 && deltaY >= 0) || (deltaX >= 0 && deltaY < 0)) {
  angle = angle + Math.PI;
}
monster.Rotation = angle;
```

...or some other combination of positive and negative values. You should be able to test out what gives you the right result for your coordinate system.

Comment: I think that `Atn2` can be used. But `deltaX / deltaY` in the question looked strange.

Comment: This does'nt work and I've heard of atan2 before but never realized how it works